# Use PHP to mask URL of image-generating CGI script

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, cgi, jpeg

I have a networked camera that generates a video snapshot upon hitting  `http://192.0.0.8/image/jpeg.cgi`. The problem is that by accessing the root (i.e. `192.0.0.8`) directly, users can access a live video feed, so I hope to hide the address altogether.

My proposed solution is to use PHP to retrieve the image and display it at `http://intranet/monitor/view.php`. Although users could create motion by hitting this new address repeatedly, I see that as unlikely.

I have tried using `include()` and `readfile()` in various ways, but do not really use PHP often enough to understand if I'm going in the right direction. My best attempt to date  resulted in outputting the jpeg contents, but I did not save the code long enough to share with you.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: put some time limit to the same user request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A succinct way to do this is as follows:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('http://192.0.0.8/image/jpeg.cgi');
```

The content of the jpeg is then streamed back to the browser as a file, directly from `http://intranet/monitor/view.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit requests per user then use this:

```
$timelimit = 30;//Limit in seconds

if(!isset($_SESSION['last_request_time'])) {
    $_SESSION['last_request_time'] = time();
}

if(time() > $_SESSION['last_request_time'] + $timelimit) {
    //prepare and serve a new image
} else {
    //serve an old image
}
```

If you want to limit image refresh time then use the same script but save the last_request_time in place shared for all users(DB, file, cache)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. I just need to hide the URL now.